# Is one of my DB-fields NOT NULL?

Tags: sql, select, null

I have to deal with a table where there is a set of fields each followed by a second field that will hold a suggested new value until this change is confirmed.

It looks a little like this:

```
refID    field1    newField1    field2    newField2   ...
```

refID is an ID value that links to a master table. One row in the master table can have n rows in my detail table. The data-types include ints, strings and dateTimes.

Now, i'm looking to have a query that tells me, given a refID, if there are any suggested changes in the detail table.

I was playing around a little with some UNION selects, with COALESCE() and ISNULL() ... but all those attempts looked a little weird at best. The DB is MS-SQL-Server 2005.

For clarification of my problem:

```
--this is a simplification of the details table in question
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TEST_TABLE](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [refID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [firstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [newFirstName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lastName] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [newLastName] [varchar](50) NULL
)

--here we insert a detail row ... one of many that might exist for the master table (e.g. data about the company)
insert into TEST_TABLE(refID, firstName, lastName) values(666, 'Bill', 'Ballmer')
--this is what happens when a user saves a suggested change
update TEST_TABLE SET newLastName = 'Gates' where ID = 1
--and this is what happens when this suggestion is accepted by a second user
update TEST_TABLE set lastName=newLastName, newLastName = NULL where ID = 1
```

Comment: Can you post some DDL for a small sample?  I'm unclear on exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the cleanest solution I can think of off the top of my head.  You'd need to repeat the logic for each data element (col1, col2, etc):

```
DECLARE @RefID int, @Changes bit

SET @Changes = 0 --No changes by default

SET @RefID = 42 --Your RefID

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM MyDetailTable
          WHERE RefID = @RefID
          AND (
          (Col1 IS NULL AND NewCol1 IS NOT NULL)
          OR 
          (Col1 IS NOT NULL AND NewCol1 IS NULL)
          OR
          (Col1 <> Col2)
          ))
   SET @Changes = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified randolphos solution.

```
 select 
        refID ,
        case when 
            newField1 is not null or
            newField2 is not null or
            ...
        then 1 else 0 end  haschanged
    from myTable
    where refID = @refID
```

Update: basically what Aron Aalton said in another output format.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple query:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 1 as found
      FROM [dbo].[TEST_TABLE] t
     WHERE COALESCE(t.newFirstName,t.newLastName) IS NOT NULL
       AND t.refID = 1
```

This query will return a single row if there are any proposed changes for a given `refID` (based on the example in your question.)

For your actual table of course, you'd need to list each of the `'newValue'` columns as arguments in the COALESCE function.  (In the coalesce list, I recommend explicitly casting any non-VARCHAR to VARCHAR, just to make it clear that every expression in the list is of the same data type.

If you prefer to use a CASE expression rather than COALESCE:

```
    SELECT TOP 1 1 as found
      FROM [dbo].[TEST_TABLE] t
     WHERE CASE 
           WHEN t.newFirstName IS NOT NULL THEN 1
           WHEN t.newLastName  IS NOT NULL THEN 1
           ELSE NULL
           END IS NOT NULL
       AND t.refID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this schema already defined and in production?  If not I would strongly recommend having a separate 'changes' table of some description - maybe use fieldname, fieldvalue where fieldvalue is a sql_variant.

I don't think your existing structure is going to look nice when values are 'accepted' (null'd I assume) especially as you won't retain any auditing history with this approach.

Comment: i wouldn't come up with a design like this. :) it's in production for years and now there are some additional features to be implemented without redesigning the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Can't test this, but perhaps:

```
select (field1 is not null and field2 is not null) as ChangesMade where refID = @id
```

Comment: unfortunately this won't work :( i get an error message : "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'is'."

Comment: SQL server doesn't allow you does kind of things with booleans.